# change text color when button onclick and (if possible) exclude some text or elements from changing colors when onclick

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make a button that when `onclick` will change all the text on the page change color including text inside divs or outside divs. If possible, can I exclude some text from changing colors like the footer or text links?

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<div class="changecolor">
<ul>
<button type="button" class="redbutton" style="background-color:red"></button>
<button type="button" class="bluebutton" style="background-color:blue"></button>
<button type="button" class="greenbutton" style="background-color:green"></button>
<button type="button" class="blackbutton" style="background-color:black"></button>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="registerbox">
    <div class="inner-registerbox">
    <div class="registerbox-icon"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></div>
        <div class="registerbox-front">
            <h2>BORANG PENDAFTARAN MURID</h2>
            <form method='POST' action=''>
            <form>
            <div class="box-firstline">
                <label for="idmurid">ID Murid</label> <br /> 
                <input type="text" name="idmurid" class="input-box2" required>
            
                <label for="namamurid">Nama Murid</label> <br /> 
                <input type="text" name="namamurid" class="input-box3" required>
            </div>
            <div class="box-secondline">
                <label for="namakelas">Nama Kelas</label> <br /> 
                <input type="text" name="namakelas" class="input-box2" required>

                <label for="katalaluan_murid">Kata Laluan</label> <br /> 
                <input type="password" name="katalaluan_murid" class="input-box3" required minlength='5' required maxlength='20' required>

                <label>Kata Laluan Sekali Lagi</label> <br /> 
                <input type="password" name="katalaluan_murid2" class="input-box3" required minlength='5' required maxlength='20' required>
            
            </div>
            <input type='submit' value='Daftar' class="registerbutton">

            <p>Sudah mempunyai akaun? <a href="index.php">Log Masuk</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?PHP include('footer.php');?>
</body>
</html>
```

css
https://jsfiddle.net/epq6s70f/

footer
https://jsfiddle.net/9poqgzxr/

Comment: Yes, it can be done. But show the general layout (header, container and footer).

Comment: Oh okay, edited it.

Comment: Ok, but why are you including the footer outside the body tag?

Comment: sorry if its a bit messy. done edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Add click handlers `changeColor` for the buttons and give the elements that you want to change some class. Everything else without the `allow-change` class will be ignored.

```js
function changeColor(color){
  $('.allow-change').css('color', color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="changecolor">
<ul>
<button type="button" class="redbutton" style="background-color:red; width: 20px; height: 10px;" onclick="changeColor('red')"></button>
<button type="button" class="bluebutton" style="background-color:blue; width: 20px; height: 10px;" onclick="changeColor('blue')"></button>
<button type="button" class="greenbutton" style="background-color:green; width: 20px; height: 10px;" onclick="changeColor('green')"></button>
<button type="button" class="blackbutton" style="background-color:black; width: 20px; height: 10px;" onclick="changeColor('black')"></button>
</ul>
</div>
<p class="allow-change">This text color can be changed</p>
<p>This text color cannot be changed</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with creating a button.
2. Give class names to all the "div" elements containing text.
3. create a CSS class with attributes changing the background-color or text color or whatever you want with those divisions.
4. select those divisions using their class names using the "document.querySelectorAll" method in javaScript.
5. Now add the CSS class you created to those divisions using (document.querySelector('class name').classList.add('Here, mention that CSS class that you created to change the colour earlier').
6. You have to add an event listener on the button

Answer (score 1):

This is an exemple of how to do all the text inside the body.

```js
$( "#red" ).click(function() {
  document.body.style.color = "red";
});
$( "#blue" ).click(function() {
  document.body.style.color = "blue";
});
$( "#green" ).click(function() {
  document.body.style.color = "green";
});
$( "#black" ).click(function() {
  document.body.style.color = "black";
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="changecolor">
some text in the div
<ul>
<button id="red" type="button" class="redbutton" style="background-color:red"></button>
<button id="blue" type="button" class="bluebutton" style="background-color:blue"></button>
<button id="green" type="button" class="greenbutton" style="background-color:green"></button>
<button id="black" type="button" class="blackbutton" style="background-color:black"></button>
</ul>

<p>some text</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: tried it. text inside div wont change color.

Comment: @underrated did your run the code snippet? because it is working on my end. i added some text inside the div and it changing colors.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do it alternatively with native Javascript.

First of all you get all the buttons with `document.getElementsByTagName` and then you iterate through each one of them and you get their class.

By getting their class, in continuation, you can split the string whenever the word "button" occurs.

After this split you can just take the name of your color and pass it to whichever element you want to in the DOM.

```js
   let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
   let body = document.getElementsByClassName("changecolor")[0];

   for(var i = 0; i< buttons.length; i++){
     let button = buttons[i];
     let color;
     button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        color = button.className.toString();
        color = color.split("button")[0];
        body.style.color = color;
    });
   }
```

```css
.redbutton, .bluebutton, .greenbutton, .blackbutton{
  padding: 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}
  .footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="changecolor">
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<ul>
<button type="button" class="redbutton" style="background-color:red">Change color</button>
<button type="button" class="bluebutton" style="background-color:blue">Change color</button>
<button type="button" class="greenbutton" style="background-color:green">Change color</button>
<button type="button" class="blackbutton" style="background-color:black">Change color</button>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<p>Hakcipta & Copy 2020 @ AidilQayyim Sistem Kuiz FizikMudah!</p>
</div>
</body>
```

I hope that can give you a hint to your problem. Cheers